# Merging partitions microSD card

Tags: partitioning, sd-card, merge

[image]

I formatted this two partitions of my microSD card and now I want to merge them.. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no easy "one step solution" to merging partitions. Fortunately, your partition is pretty small. It'll be easy to combine the two.

1. Mount `/dev/sdc2` (the smaller partition).
2. Copy all of its files to the Desktop or another temporary location.
3. In GParted, delete that partition, and then extend out `/dev/sdc1` to use all available free space.
4. Mount the newly-resized `/dev/sdc1` and copy all files from your desktop back to the SD card.

---

If the partitions are empty (or you don't care about losing what's on `/dev/sdc2`), you can simply delete the partition then resize `/dev/sdc1` out. Note that you **will** lose anything on that partition.

Comment: I was just putting this in a comment :) It is the best solution for a small USB stick +1